# Reset Application State in Emberjs

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In my application i have button and want when user click on this my Application Completing Reset that means clear/empty model session or any data that will created . according to [this](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/235) topic i try `App.reset()` but it dose not work.

Comment: It should work. Is your app called App? When you create your app, you can name it anything you like. For example, if your app is defined like so: MyApp = Ember.Application.create(); you would need to do you would have to use MyApp.reset(). You also need to be using Ember version 1.0 RC1.

What isn't working? Is there an error?

Comment: my app creating is `var OlapApp = Ember.Application.createWithMixins(Bootstrap.Register,{});`

Answer (score 2):

`OlapApp.Reset()` resets Ember.

`store.unloadAll(type)` empties out all of that type in the Data store.

Comment: it should be OlapApp.reset()

Comment: in my controller call `OlapApp.reset()` but it dosent reset app and empty models.